# Enable checkbox if there is enough credit balance

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" id="star1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="star2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="star3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="star4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="star5" />
<input type="button" value="Build" onclick="build()" />

function build(){
var balance = 300;
for (var i =1; i < 6; i++) {

    if(document.getElementById("star"+i).checked) {
        balance = balance - 100;
    }
}
$("#bal").text("Balance: $" + balance);
}
```

In my example code the player has a balance of $300 which means he can only afford to build either 1star, 2star, 3star hotel. Each hotel costs $100 to build. So when he checks the 4th checkbox an error message should appear to say "You can't afford it mate."

Comment: Use an if statement inside your loop. It will go something like `if (balance >= 100)`...

Comment: meagar the balance should be compared to the "cost" of building the hotels...or do you mean that the loop makes sure each time the balance is at least => 100.. hmm,

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes? Wouldn't radio buttons be more appropriate if the user is to select between different types of things?

Comment: I didn't know radio buttons were better suited. The player needs to select 1 thing yes but I want to allow him to uncheck, that was not possible with radio buttons...

Comment: So the user can select *only one* of the the hotel types?

Comment: Note: This is for a monpoly game. Where the player wants to build house. I just use hotels and star rating as that it is much simpler than the 4 houses and then on the 5th build they become hotels.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes only 1 type of hotel, but for example if you want a 2 star hotel, for visual purpose you must select 2 checkboxes.

Comment: The last line looks like jQuery code. Are you using jQuery? Also, if you want the user to be able to "uncheck", you could provide a radio button for "no selection." You could event consider a `<select>` element.

Comment: yes I am using jquery also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using radio buttons, with an option for "no selection." Also, you could put `value` attributes on the radio buttons, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="hotel" checked="checked" /> No selection
<input type="radio" name="hotel" id="star1" value="100" /> 1 star
<input type="radio" name="hotel" id="star2" value="200" /> 2 star
```

You could then check the balance against the value of the selected radio button to see if the user can afford it.

Here is what the jQuery code could look like:

```
var $selectedHotel = $('input:radio[name=hotel][value]:checked');
if ($selectedHotel.length > 0) {
    var cost = parseInt($selectedHotel.val(), 10);
    if (cost > balance) {
        alert("Sorry mate, you can't afford that!");
    } else {
        alert("You built it, mate!");
    }
} else {
    alert('You must select something first.');
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2t3g/)

The following selector gets all the radio buttons with "hotel" for the `name` attribute and that have a `value` attribute (which excludes the "no selection" button) and are checked, which should be at most one button.

`'input:radio[name=hotel][value]:checked'`:

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are putting in $selectedHotel on the first line? What is going on at [name=hotel[value]:checked ?

Comment: @EltonFrederik - I added an explanation to the bottom of my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i =1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if(document.getElementById("star"+i).checked) {
        if(balance > 100)
            balance -= 100;
        else
            alert("You can't afford it mate.");
    }
}
```

This is the fix for your actual code, but it doesn't resemble the functionality that you're describing. That functionality will however simply not work with the user interface you designed (you can check the 4th box without the first 3), so you've got more problems to solve first.

Comment: You are right. I am trying to let the user choose what type of hotel he wants to build. Check if he can afford it. At the moment the fix alerts him that he can't afford it but it completed part of the build that he could afford.